# Generic JavaScript parser for user supplied coordinates

Tags: javascript, parsing, geocoding, latitude-longitude

Is there a JavaScript library that can help with parsing coordinates in various formats provided by users?

I have a map site with a search box that can be used for searching place names, but looking through the stats I'm seeing a lot of people trying to use coordinates in various formats directly, much like they are able to do on Google Maps.

Typical variations of latitudes and longitudes I see are:

```
-43 02 42.845 S 172 38 33.790 E
n 19°49'2.30e 41°51'29.20
41°46'57.90"S
172° 1'20.39"E 43 02 42.845 S
42.897S 172.720E
42.31.303 172.23.379
19.817306°, 41.858111°
```

That's a lot of variations, which is only a sample. Then there are users trying various New Zealand formats based on NZTM and NZMG.

Ideally I'd like to find a library that someone may have started with some basic latitudes and longitudes then extend the functionality to support other formats I see coming through.

Anyone know of anything already out there?

Comment: Do you have on–screen help saying "Please enter latitude then longitude in the format +/-ddd mm ss.s" or separate fields for latitude and longitude? Otherwise you will have very convoluted logic to sort out the mess. The last two are completely ambiguous, though you might guess that the first number is latitude since that's the convention.

Comment: I give no indication of lat lon formats required. In fact, the functionality was never intended for this - I'm just reacting to how some users are trying to use the functionality (probably from their experiences with Google Maps). I actually want to be as flexible as possible, allowing as many formats as possible to be supported. I figured I could come up with some generic search provider library that uses regex to see if format meets criteria of that specific provider. Should keep it easy to extend and add more support for formats without becoming too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To parse numeric coordinates from raw text input**, there is npm package [coordinate-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coordinate-parser) by [otto-dev](https://github.com/otto-dev/coordinate-parser). It feels robust for [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) latitude-longitude pairs and their minute and decimal representations.

```
const CoordinateParser = require('coordinate-parser')
const text = `60 40' 31.35" N, 23 50' 55.75" E`
const pos = new CoordinateParser(text)
const lat = pos.getLatitude() // 60.675374
const lng = pos.getLongitude() // 23.848819
```

**While proper for WGS84**, coordinate-parser does not handle [UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) coordinates, such as the ones on [NZTM](https://epsg.io/2193) or [ETRS89 TM35FIN](https://epsg.io/3067), for example `N 6730758, E 327874`. The parser treats the large numbers as milliseconds or densely formatted DDMMSS.xxx instead of metres, thus yielding invalid results.

**For UTM coordinates** there is [utm-coordinate-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utm-coordinate-parser). It recognises common easting-northing pairs such as `6730758 N 327874 E` as well as x-y pairs `x:327874 y:6730758`. Disclaimer: I am the package author.

```
const utmp = require('utm-coordinate-parser')
const text = 'N 6730758; W -327874'
const pos = utmp.parse(text)
const x = pos.x // 327874
const y = pos.y // 6730758
```

Answer (score 1):

I've actually just published my JavaScript library called Magellan that handles formatting and validation of latitude/longitude coordinates like the ones you listed above. Check it out and see if it is what you were looking for.

Link here: https://dbarbalato.github.io/magellan/

As a quick note, It wouldn't handle EVERY format you listed above, but I'm open to expanding the functionality if there is enough interest.

Comment: Hi Dave, looks very promising! I might have to have a play and see if I can re-factor it to allow formats to be plugged-in. Thanks for sharing! I'll let you know how I get on.

Answer (score -2):

The general form should be:

```
var m;
if( m = input.match(/format regex here/)) { /* do stuff with m */ }
else if( m = input.match(/another format/)) { /* do stuff with m */ }
...
else {throw new Error("Format not recognised!");}
```

It'll be up to you to build the regexes you need, but they should be too hard since they're relatively simple formats.

Comment: I was thinking of something more generic that I can plug more format parsers in to as required, but basically you're on to the right idea. I figured my problem is something that has probably been solved before, so why re-invent the wheel if there's a library / solution already out there that perhaps handles more formats than I've encountered so far and I can build on.